# Properly align in-memory template, invariant of order of parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, memory-alignment

Take a look at this template.

```
template < typename T1, typename T2, typename T3 >
struct Alignement {
    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    T3 third;
};

int main() {
    Alignement<char, int, double> a1;
    Alignement<char, double, int> a2;
    assert( sizeof(a1) < sizeof(a2) );
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously assertion holds. Sub-optimal ordering leads to 50% more memory usage in this case.

My question is, what are the ways of combating it and properly ordering types in template structure, other than kindly asking user to take care of it himself (which would leave him with the same problem if he didn't know sizes of his types beforehand)?

My idea is to generate optimal ordering dynamically at compile time with macros or TMP, but I have no proper knowledge of these techniques. Or perhaps an army of partially specialized templates would get the job done?

The key aspect is preserving the `AlignedObject.first` syntax for client.

For my specific case, I'm looking for solution for exactly 3 parameters (3! possible orderings) but general solution (including variadic-length-templates) would be interesting to see.

Comment: Can you have duplicated types as argument? `Alignment<char, int, int>`?

Comment: The general technique is to order the declaration of struct members with largest first.   I wouldn't bother writing a template to do it.

Comment: Particularly if the types can be duplicated it would be far better to simply tell the user to take care of it.

Comment: I don't see this being possible for variadic-lenght-templates as the only solution I can see involves recursive inheritance. This in itself violates the [standard layout concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType).

Comment: Do you accept C++17 solutions?

Comment: @JVApen Yes, duplicates are a possibility. There are no constraints on types.

Comment: @Peter Of course. Smallest to largest works equally well. Problem is, how to determine that order? Obviously my template is a minimal example, it would be doing much more than that, and then be written to disk (or stored in memory) in huge arrays ~1GB. Here, 500MB makes large difference, hence this question.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir 
This is just minimal example. We assume user has no simple way of predicting size of those types ( they are templates types as well, he just provides some arguments for them ), so he can only use sizeof(), and think of a similar solution as I'm looking for. 
Of course, he could do that manually... but only if he could run the code on his own types, which is not guaranteed if he writes a template himself.

Comment: @super variadics would be just nice bonus for satisfying my curiosity or as a exercise for a reader :P I really need it just for 3, max 4 parameters.

Comment: @max66 would have to update compiler but sure :)

Comment: @MkjG - smallest to largest works well if you want to maximise the size of the containing class.   Rather poorly if the intent is to minimise the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For my specific case, I'm looking for solution for exactly 3 parameters (3! possible orderings) but general solution (including variadic-length-templates) would be interesting to see.

I propose a general solution: a variadic type sorter and a variadic `Alignement` that use it.

Following the Peter's suggestion, the idea is to sort the type putting biggers types first.

<s>I use C++17 because the new template folding permit</s> I use C++11 because the OP must use a C++11 only compliant compiler to make <s>extremely simple</s> a type traits that say if the first type of a list is the bigger one (according `sizeof()`). I maintain, commented, the original C++17 version

```
// iftb = is first type bigger ?

// original C++17 version
//
// template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
// struct iftb
//    : public std::integral_constant<bool,((sizeof(Ts) <= sizeof(T0)) && ...)>
//  { };

template <typename ...>
struct iftb;

template <typename T0>
struct iftb<T0> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct iftb<T0, T1, Ts...>
   : public std::integral_constant<bool,
        (sizeof(T1) <= sizeof(T0)) && iftb<T0, Ts...>::value>
 { };
```

Now a type traits to know if a type container contain a list of ordered types

```
// ifctb = is first contained type bigger ?
template <typename>
struct ifctb;

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename ... Tc>
struct ifctb<C<Tc...>> : public iftb<Tc...>
 { };
```

Now the type orderer is simple to write (but not particularly efficient; sorry)

```
// to = type orderer
template <typename, typename Cd, bool = ifctb<Cd>::value>
struct to;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... To,
          typename T0, typename ... Tu>
struct to<C<To...>, C<T0, Tu...>, true> : public to<C<To..., T0>, C<Tu...>>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... To,
          typename T0, typename ... Tu>
struct to<C<To...>, C<T0, Tu...>, false> : public to<C<To...>, C<Tu..., T0>>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... To, typename T>
struct to<C<To...>, C<T>, true>
 { using type = C<To..., T>; };
```

Now I propose an indexed wrapper that must be defined through partial specialization to define `first`, `second` and `third` (etc., if you want extend the solution)

```
template <std::size_t, typename>
struct wrapper;

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<0U, T>
 { T first; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<1U, T>
 { T second; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<2U, T>
 { T third; };
```

We need `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` that are available only starting from C++14; but the OP must compile this code in a C++11 only compliant compiler so I propose a simple emulation C++11 compliant

```
// std::index_sequence and std::make_index_sequence simplified emulators
template <std::size_t...>
struct indexSequence
 { using type = indexSequence; };

template <typename, typename>
struct concatSequences;

template <std::size_t... S1, std::size_t... S2>
struct concatSequences<indexSequence<S1...>, indexSequence<S2...>>
   : public indexSequence<S1..., ( sizeof...(S1) + S2 )...>
 { };

template <std::size_t N>
struct makeIndexSequenceH
   : public concatSequences<
               typename makeIndexSequenceH<(N>>1)>::type,
               typename makeIndexSequenceH<N-(N>>1)>::type>::type
 { };

template<>
struct makeIndexSequenceH<0> : public indexSequence<>
 { };

template<>
struct makeIndexSequenceH<1> : public indexSequence<0>
 { };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename makeIndexSequenceH<N>::type;
```

With the help of `std::tuple`, <s>`std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`</s> `indexSequence` and `makeIndexSequence` (C++11 compliant simplified emulations of `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`), I add a couples of helper `struct`s for `Alignement`

```
template <typename>
struct AlH2;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct AlH2<std::tuple<Ts...>> : public Ts...
 { };

template <typename...>
struct AlH1;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct AlH1<indexSequence<Is...>, Ts...>
   : public AlH2<typename to<std::tuple<>,
                             std::tuple<wrapper<Is, Ts>...>>::type>
 { };
```

Now `Alignement` can be written as

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct Alignement
  : public AlH1<makeIndexSequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>
 { };
```

The following is a full <s>(I remember: C++17)</s> C++11 compiling example with some `assert()`'s to verify the correct ordering.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// std::index_sequence and std::make_index_sequence simplified emulators
template <std::size_t...>
struct indexSequence
 { using type = indexSequence; };

template <typename, typename>
struct concatSequences;

template <std::size_t... S1, std::size_t... S2>
struct concatSequences<indexSequence<S1...>, indexSequence<S2...>>
   : public indexSequence<S1..., ( sizeof...(S1) + S2 )...>
 { };

template <std::size_t N>
struct makeIndexSequenceH
   : public concatSequences<
               typename makeIndexSequenceH<(N>>1)>::type,
               typename makeIndexSequenceH<N-(N>>1)>::type>::type
 { };

template<>
struct makeIndexSequenceH<0> : public indexSequence<>
 { };

template<>
struct makeIndexSequenceH<1> : public indexSequence<0>
 { };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename makeIndexSequenceH<N>::type;

// iftb = is first type bigger ?

// original C++17 version
//
// template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
// struct iftb
//    : public std::integral_constant<bool,((sizeof(Ts) <= sizeof(T0)) && ...)>
//  { };

template <typename ...>
struct iftb;

template <typename T0>
struct iftb<T0> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct iftb<T0, T1, Ts...>
   : public std::integral_constant<bool,
        (sizeof(T1) <= sizeof(T0)) && iftb<T0, Ts...>::value>
 { };

// ifctb = is first contained type bigger ?
template <typename>
struct ifctb;

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename ... Tc>
struct ifctb<C<Tc...>>
   : public iftb<Tc...>
 { };

// to = type orderer
template <typename, typename Cd, bool = ifctb<Cd>::value>
struct to;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... To,
          typename T0, typename ... Tu>
struct to<C<To...>, C<T0, Tu...>, true> : public to<C<To..., T0>, C<Tu...>>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... To,
          typename T0, typename ... Tu>
struct to<C<To...>, C<T0, Tu...>, false> : public to<C<To...>, C<Tu..., T0>>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... To, typename T>
struct to<C<To...>, C<T>, true>
 { using type = C<To..., T>; };

template <std::size_t, typename>
struct wrapper;

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<0U, T>
 { T first; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<1U, T>
 { T second; };

template <typename T>
struct wrapper<2U, T>
 { T third; };

template <typename>
struct AlH2;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct AlH2<std::tuple<Ts...>> : public Ts...
 { };

template <typename...>
struct AlH1;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct AlH1<indexSequence<Is...>, Ts...>
   : public AlH2<typename to<std::tuple<>,
                             std::tuple<wrapper<Is, Ts>...>>::type>
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Alignement
  : public AlH1<makeIndexSequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>
 { };


int main ()
 {
   Alignement<char, int, long long>  a0;

   a0.first  = '0';
   a0.second = 1;
   a0.third  = 2LL;

   assert( (std::size_t)&a0.third < (std::size_t)&a0.first );
   assert( (std::size_t)&a0.third < (std::size_t)&a0.second );
   assert( (std::size_t)&a0.second < (std::size_t)&a0.first );
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> using your solution, if I want to achieve N-argument template class, I need to define N wrapper classes, each containing single field name for n-th argument. Different Alignement<>'s should have different field names == set of N wrappers for each of them. Any good idea for a macro (or template...) to achieve that?

For me, C-style macros are distilled evil (and I don't know they very well), but...

What I propose isn't a full solution; only a draft.

If you define the following set of macros

```
#define WrpNum(wName, num, fName) \
   template <typename T>\
   struct wrapper_ ## wName <num, T> \
    { T fName; };

#define Foo_1(wName, tot, fName) \
   WrpNum(wName, tot-1U, fName)

#define Foo_2(wName, tot, fName, ...) \
   WrpNum(wName, tot-2U, fName) \
   Foo_1(wName, tot, __VA_ARGS__)

#define Foo_3(wName, tot, fName, ...) \
   WrpNum(wName, tot-3U, fName) \
   Foo_2(wName, tot, __VA_ARGS__)

// Foo_4(), Foo_5(), ...

#define Foo(wName, num, ...) \
   template <std::size_t, typename> \
   struct wrapper_ ## wName; \
   Foo_ ## num(wName, num, __VA_ARGS__)
```

you can define a template indexed `struct` `wrapper_wrp1` with specializations and a `first` member in `wrapper_wrp1<0U, T>` specialization, a `second` member in `wrapper_wrp1<1U, T>`, etc, calling

```
Foo(wrp1, 3, first, second, third)
```

Observe that you need the total number of specializations as second parameter.

Maybe is possible to make better (with recursive variadic macro?) but, frankly, I'm not interested too much in macros.

Given this call

```
Foo(wrp1, 3, first, second, third)
```

you could (caution: not tested) modify `AlH1` the specific wrapper struct (`wrapper_wrp1`)

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct AlH1<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
   : public AlH2<typename to<std::tuple<>,
                             std::tuple<wrapper_wrp1<Is, Ts>...>>::type>
 { };
```

Comment: One part is done, but OP wants to access to T1 with `first` (even if it is placed elsewhere)...

Comment: @Jarod42 - Ops! Do you mean I've correctly solved the wrong problem?

Comment: While great solution, I thank you for it!, it does not pass the requirement syntax. But, frankly, it's so complex I don't understand it fully and since it's 1 AM I will have to reread and compile it tomorrow. Maybe my minimal example wasn't specific enough and I apologize for it. The client needs to be able to access fields in the following way (just a silly example):  

`struct CFamilyMember; Alignement< tuple<CFamilyMember, string>, CallingPolicy<MyStruct>, ConfigOptions > alignement` 

It wouldn't make sense to the client for the field  
`alignement.personal_data` to return reference

Comment: to the `CallingPolicy` type. I'm sorry for being overly verbose. Jarod42's point was sufficient. I'm relatively new to CS and it's sometimes hard to communicate my thoughts concisely. While great solution, it would still require some way to "bind" the identifier-name with the type (without using reflection). So at the very least you've very impressively and correctly solved half of the problem :)

Comment: @MkjG - No, the error is mine (and Jarod42 informed me); sorry: if you want maintain `first` of type `T1`... no idea. I leave it if can be of inspiration for someone else but my solution is clearly wrong.

Comment: @MkjG - thinking a little about it... adding the use of an indexed wrapper... Answer modified; I suppose now is better.

Comment: @max66 I must say, this code is so great I don't even fully understand it :D But it certainly works. Somewhat. My question is: using your solution, if I want to achieve N-argument template class, I need to define N wrapper classes, each containing single *field name* for n-th argument. Different Alignement<>'s should have different field names == set of N wrappers for each of them. Any good idea for a macro (or template...) to achieve that?`MACRO_DECLARE_FIELDS(AlignedStruct, firstFieldName, secondFieldName, ...); AlignedStruct<double, int, int, char> align; a.firstFieldName = 3.14lf`

Comment: @max66 or perhaps (after macro): `template <typename Ts...> AlignedStructProper : public AlignedStruct<make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>,  Ts...)>` so I can add member functions `sillyF() const { cout << firstFieldName; }`

Comment: @MkjG - Uhmmm... IMHO, macros are distilled evil; anyway, thinking on it.

Comment: @MkjG - answer improved; added a variadic macro example (just a draft) to define a `wrapper_ ## name` `struct`. I suppose It's can be done better but I'm not expert ofC-style macros.

Comment: @max66 I've just checked, and our university's laboratory doesn't have c++17 nor 14 compilers. Solution needs to be in c++11. I'm only asking to bother you again because you have invited me to in the original post :) Just to be specific: this is not a homework question, just a small part of a large semester project ( Non-relational database with some query language ). I'm using your solution to tightly pack trivial, standard-layout types inside 512/4096 bytes buffer (for B+Tree). ( For non-POD types I have custom serialization policy, but for PODs I can just write `char* block; (TNode*)block;`

Comment: @MkjG - the bad part isn't that isn't C++17 (no template folding); the bad part is that isn't C++14 (no `std::make_index_sequence` and no `std::index_sequence`; but they can be simulated). In this moment I can't but in some hour I try to downgrade to C++11 the solution.

Comment: @MkjG - answer modified; now the example is full C++11 compliant (but the C++17 version was better :( ).

Comment: @max66 I've marked this answer as accepted. However, there still is tiny, tiny bug in code: When declaring wrappers with macro, Foo(wrp1, 3, first, second, third) assigns "first" field name to THIRD template typename (because it gets wrapped into Foo_3<2U, ....>. In consequence, the order is reversed. It's no biggie, but I just wonder is there a simple solution? I don't see one, cause we can't reverse __VA__ARGS__, and if we starting expanding from Foo_0, we don't know when to stop?

Comment: @MkjG - I know... isn't a bug, is the way is implemented. I suppose other solutions are possibles, but you realized the problem: I don't know how stop "recursion" (not exactly recursion... a sort of) if we start from `Foo_0`. But thinking a little on it... I have an idea... adding another element... not sure that can work; give me some time to try.

Comment: @max66 I've found a solution, here is around 90% of it: https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms I will be updating my question with all macros after I finish them.

Comment: @max66 hey, it's me again :D `Alignement< char[9], double, int > fails; std::cout << sizeof(fails) << std::endl;` Structure is 32 bytes, but with optimal ordering should be only 24bytes. The reason, as I understand it, is sorting by total size (using sizeof... to expand), and should be sorting by alignement, to properly accommodate array and custom types. Is there an easy way to sort by `alignof` or `std::alignement_of`?

Comment: This also fails: `struct huge {
 char v[10*alignof(double)+1];
};

struct aligned_better {
 double d;
 int i;
 huge h;
}; Alignement < huge, double, int > custom_POD_fails; `

Comment: @MkjG - macro improved to write `Foo(wrp1, 3, first, second, third)`; it was easy.

Comment: @MkjG - not sure about the order of arrays; which order do you think is right for `Alignement< char[9], double, int>` ?

Comment: Decreasing alignment size. I think? All I know about this subject is from this article: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/ Ordering member types in decreasing alignment means that every "variable" or array element will start in-memory well-aligned - padding will be added only at "the end" of structure and will be at most `alignof(align_of_largest_member)-1` Same holds true for increasing alignment (but it's less obvious). Your code already sorts perfectly, I just need sorting by the value returned by `alignof()` in `public AlH1<makeIndexSequence<alignof...(Ts)>, Ts...>` -this fails obv

Comment: @max66 or std::alignment_of<T>::value like in other 2 answers in this question, whatever is better suited to use in your code. (i forgot to mention you in my last comment :) )

Comment: @MkjG - I see... so you need (if I understand correctly) `char[9]` in last position. Well... do you've changed `(sizeof(T1) <= sizeof(T0))` with `(std::alignment_of<T1>::value <= std::alignment_of<T0>::value)` ?

Comment: @max66 Oh, I'm dumb D: sizeof... returns number of variadic parameters, not actual sizes of types. It wasn't doing magic, it was just returning single value... Changing sorting condition works of course, now every array type and custom type (as long as it's Standard-Layout, I think?) takes minimal amount of memory <3 I'll update my question with full code and macros sometime tomorrow (there's no need to specify number of arguments).

Comment: @max66 Or maybe it's better to update your answer? What's better practice on SO? Macro that avoids specifying number of arguments [Assuming Foo_1, Foo_2, etc. as in your answer]: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IJ6UC (forgive me linking like that, but would be unreadable in comments)

Comment: @MkjG - nice improvement for macro number of arguments. For update question/answer... I suppose is better modify both when there is a general interest in question. I don't know, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... O>
struct SizeOrder;

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Rest>
struct SizeOrder<T1, T2, Rest...> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<(T1::size::value > T2::size::value || (T1::size::value == T2::size::value && T1::order::value < T2::order::value)), typename SizeOrder<T2, Rest...>::type, int>::type;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct SizeOrder<T1, T2> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<(T1::size::value > T2::size::value || (T1::size::value == T2::size::value && T1::order::value < T2::order::value)), void, int>::type;
};

template <typename... T>
using Order = typename SizeOrder<T...>::type;

template <typename T1, int T2>
struct DeclarationOrder {
    using size = typename std::alignment_of<T1>;
    using order = typename std::integral_constant<int, T2>;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename = void>
struct Alignement;

#define AO DeclarationOrder<A,1>
#define BO DeclarationOrder<B,2>
#define CO DeclarationOrder<C,3>

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Alignement<A, B, C, Order<AO, BO, CO>> {
    A first;
    B second;
    C third;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Alignement<A, B, C, Order<AO, CO, BO>> {
    A first;
    C third;
    B second;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Alignement<A, B, C, Order<BO, AO, CO>> {
    B second;
    A first;
    C third;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Alignement<A, B, C, Order<BO, CO, AO>> {
    B second;
    C third;
    A first;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Alignement<A, B, C, Order<CO, AO, BO>> {
    C third;
    A first;
    B second;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Alignement<A, B, C, Order<CO, BO, AO>> {
    C third;
    B second;
    A first;
};


int main() {
    Alignement<char, int, double> t1;
    std::cout << sizeof(t1) << std::endl << sizeof(t1.first) << std::endl << sizeof(t1.second) << std::endl << std::endl;

    Alignement<char, double, int> t2;
    std::cout << sizeof(t2) << std::endl << sizeof(t2.first) << std::endl << sizeof(t2.second) << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Added a Order<> template to recursively check the size-order of any amount of parameters and extended Aligenment to hold 3 variables.

EDIT2: Template deduction failed when using types with same size, so I changed the `SizeOrder template` to take a `DeclarationOrder` template to remove the ambiguity from having 2 possible orders for something like `Alignement<int, int, double>`

With some testing on [godbolt](http://godbolt.org) to figure out the macro part we can condense the whole thing to this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... O>
struct SizeOrder;

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Rest>
struct SizeOrder<T1, T2, Rest...> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<(T1::size::value > T2::size::value || (T1::size::value == T2::size::value && T1::order::value < T2::order::value)), typename SizeOrder<T2, Rest...>::type, int>::type;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct SizeOrder<T1, T2> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<(T1::size::value > T2::size::value || (T1::size::value == T2::size::value && T1::order::value < T2::order::value)), void, int>::type;
};

template <typename... T>
using Order = typename SizeOrder<T...>::type;

template <typename T1, int T2>
struct DeclarationOrder {
    using size = typename std::alignment_of<T1>;
    using order = typename std::integral_constant<int, T2>;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename = void>
struct Alignement;

#define AO DeclarationOrder<A,1>
#define BO DeclarationOrder<B,2>
#define CO DeclarationOrder<C,3>

#define Aname first
#define Bname second
#define Cname third

#define MAKE_SPECIALIZATION(FIRST, SECOND, THIRD) \
template <typename A, typename B, typename C> \
struct Alignement<A, B, C, Order<FIRST ## O, SECOND ## O,  THIRD ## O>> { \
    FIRST FIRST ## name; \
    SECOND SECOND ## name; \
    THIRD THIRD ## name; \
};

MAKE_SPECIALIZATION(A,B,C)
MAKE_SPECIALIZATION(A,C,B)
MAKE_SPECIALIZATION(B,A,C)
MAKE_SPECIALIZATION(B,C,A)
MAKE_SPECIALIZATION(C,A,B)
MAKE_SPECIALIZATION(C,B,A)


int main() {
    Alignement<char, int, double> t1;
    std::cout << sizeof(t1) << std::endl << sizeof(t1.first) << std::endl << sizeof(t1.second) << std::endl << std::endl;

    Alignement<char, double, int> t2;
    std::cout << sizeof(t2) << std::endl << sizeof(t2.first) << std::endl << sizeof(t2.second) << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To extend it to 4, 5 or 6 variables we need to update `struct Alignement` to add `template D` before `template = void`. Then we `#define DO DeclarationOrder<D,4>` and `#define Dname fourth`.

Then we add a `D` and `FOURTH` to the `MAKE_SPECIALIZATION` macro and define all (16?) possible layouts.

Far from squeaky clean, but doable.

Comment: And note that without some get<>() that is able to go from parameter to storage order this is pretty much useless. It doesn't matter much if you do a .second without knowing which type that will be.

Comment: first would always refer to the first template parameter, and second to the second one... so you do know. It's only the internal storage order that is different.

Comment: Frankly, thats not a solution because `sizeof(Alignement<int,double>) == sizeof(Alignement<double,int>)` - two fields will always be optimally ordered, because the compiler inserts padding after last field as well, but I do get the idea and can expand it for 6 cases. Also, the number of needed specialization grows with factorial ( 24 for 4 parameters ) so I'll hold on marking that answer as accepted; I'd prefer something less cumbersome to type manually, though it does seem easy to construct macro for given N and copy-paste it N! times. How would one achieve that with one-liner macro?

Comment: Agreed. It is a proof of concept, but not the full solution to your problem. From this it should be easy to extend to what you want.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir We want to specifically avoid any `get<>()` syntax, and this solution does avoid it, as super pointed out.

Comment: @super Well, I only just need that one line macro and it would be something I could use.

Comment: @MkjG Macros is not my thing, so not sure how to make that magic macro. I did however update the answer to simplify the syntax needed to construct the specializations.

Answer (score 1):

For the three-member case (or any other fixed number) you can use a *sorting network* to efficiently reduce the number of specializations (at best, log^2n swaps AFAIR); in C++11, something like (not tested):

```
template <typename T,std::size_t> struct MemberSpec: std::alignment_of<T> {};

struct NoMember{};
template<typename, typename = NoMember> struct MemberDecl{};
template<typename T, typename B> struct MemberDecl<MemberSpec<T,0>,B>: B { T first; };
template<typename T, typename B> struct MemberDecl<MemberSpec<T,1>,B>: B { T second; };
template<typename T, typename B> struct MemberDecl<MemberSpec<T,2>,B>: B { T third; };

template<typename M0,typename M1,typename M2>
struct Alignement_01: std::conditional_t<( M0::value < M1::value ),
  MemberDecl<M0,MemberDecl<M1,MemberDecl<M2>>>, MemberDecl<M1,MemberDecl<M0,MemberDecl<M2>>> >{};

template<typename M0,typename M1,typename M2>
struct Alignement_02: std::conditional_t<( M0::value < M2::value ),
  Alignement_01<M0,M1,M2>, Alignement_01<M2,M1,M0> >{};

template<typename M0,typename M1,typename M2>
struct Alignement_12: std::conditional_t<( M1::value < M2::value ),
  Alignement_02<M0,M1,M2>, Alignement_02<M0,M2,M1> >{};

template<typename T0,typename T1,typename T2>
struct Alignement: Alignement_12<MemberSpec<T0,0>,MemberSpec<T1,1>,MemberSpec<T2,2>> {};
```

<strike>in the above, the resulting `Alignment<T0,T1,T2>` is standard layout since C++14 (and an aggregate since C++17), whenever the `Tj` are. This means that you'll need to place asserts to check proper field ordering and total size in pre-C++14.</strike>

EDIT: I forgot that, even in >=C++14, at most a base class can have non static data members; so, my `Alignment<>` is almost never standard layout; anyway, any decent compiler should place the fields the expected way, or better if it fits so. This may be acceptable considering that your goal is to help the compiler producing a more optimized layout.

The general case is solved similarly by implementing a sorting algorithm, or generalizing the above to work over some sorting-network abstraction; anyway, you'll still need to specialize something like `MemberDecl` to get your data member naming right (*first,second,third,fourth,...* whatever).

Comment: My understanding is that a class is not guaranteed to have [StandardLayoutType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) if it itself holds non-static data members and it inherits from other classes that also holds non-static data members. Is this wrong?

Comment: @super you're right, I forgot that at most one base can have non static data members, even in >=c++14, editing ...